# Counting occurrence of a word in a 2D char array

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops, char

I am trying to **count the number of occurrences** of each word in the array and store it. I also want the **index of the most occurring word**.

I have a 2D char array called `words`

An integer array that stores the number of occurrences is called `count`

Total number of words in `words` is called `totalWords`

So far I have done the following:

I have filled `words` with the following:

```
strcpy(words[0], "Me");
strcpy(words[1], "You");
strcpy(words[2], "Me");
strcpy(words[3], "They");


for (i = 0; i < totalWords; i++){

        count[i] = //need help here

        printf("%d times\n ", count[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use strcmp() to compare the strings in a loop, for loop for instance. Increment the counter if the words match.

```
char *words[] = {
    "Me",
    "You",
    "Me",
    "They",
};
int i;
int j;
int counter = 0;
int temp = 0;

char *longest = NULL;

//loop to compare the words in your array of strings to
//other words in the array
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(j = i + 1; j < 4; j++) {
        if(strcmp(*(words + i), *(words + j)) == 0) {
            temp++;
        }
    }
    if (temp > counter) {
        counter = temp;
        longest = *(words + i);
    }
    temp = 0;
}

printf("For word \"%s\": %d match\n", longest,counter);
```

You may also want to consider having an array of struct, with your struct having a string type and an int that stores the no. of matches, for a more systematic storage of output in this loop.